# Firebase Version :-Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Xc', but it was: a custom Zc object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
   const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000) + 1);

    const data = {
        timestamp: Timestamp.now().seconds,
        uid: `${currentUser.uid}+${x}`,
        email: currentUser.email,
        fromDate: fromDate,
        toDate: toDate,
        city: city,
        para: para,
        totalexpense: TotalExpense,
        itinerary: itinerary
    }
    console.log(data)

    await setDoc(collectionGroup(db, "experiences", currentUser.email, currentUser.email), {...data}) // error

}
```

I'm Taking input from a form and want to send the data  as collection of collection in firebase V9 , but when i'm submmiting the data its showing above error

Comment: If the following does not work, please update your question with a screenshot of your Firestore database and specify where you are trying to add the document.

Answer (score 0):

The `setDoc()` takes a `DocumentReference` as a paramter. Try:

```
const docRef = doc(db, "experiences", currentUser.email);

await setDoc(docRef, {...data})
```